# se puede buscar Ajax Buscar en DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas quisiera que me ayuden soy nuevo en c# y la verdad no se si se puede hacer en que en un DropDownList esta cargado ese combo con una base de datos que llena pero lo que quiero es que seleccione un valor y automaticamente se llene mi texbox como ajax no se usa . puede ser que me cierren la pregunta. si me podrian ayudar o un ejemplo por favor .

Como un Buscador real tan solo mostrar cualquier valor del DropDownList

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   protected void dprTarea_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string oficinas = "";
            oficinas = lblagencia.Text = Session["oficina"].ToString();

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn = new SqlConnection("server=172.16.1.124;    database=DBProAuxQP_QA;      user id=sa;                   password=SA123456789*;");
            conn.Open();

            string query = "select Fechacumplimiento from TTareasIngreso where descripcion='" + dprTarea.SelectedValue + "' ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {

                TxtFechaPago.Text = dr["Fechacumplimiento"].ToString();


            }
        }
```

Comment: Tu pregunta en si sería ¿Se puede cambiar la fecha de un `input` por medio un `select`? Es lo que entiendo

Comment: @Jorius si asi mismo me puedes ayudar por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sintaxis Correcta seria :

```
protected void dprTarea_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var val = dprTarea.SelectedItem.Value;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=172.16.1.124;    database=DBProAuxQP_QA;      user id=sa;                   password=SA123456789*;"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_TTAREABUSCARFECHA", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@descripcionrubro", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = val;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@agencia", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lblagencia.Text;
                    con.Open();
                    TxtFechaPago.Text = (String)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }

            }
}
```

Ademas para que funcione y seleccione un DropDownList tiene que estar activado el atributo AutoPostBack="true" ya que sin esta propiedad el DropDownList no va funcionar.
Por ejemplo asi debe estar:

```
  runat="server" Enabled="False" Height="16px" Width="162px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dprTarea_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Comment: No olvides que puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta.

Comment: @Davlio hermano que es de tu vida , gracias por todo :D

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el valor a un TextBox cuando seleccionas un elemento de DropDownList tenes que usar el evento SelectedIndexChanged, ahí pones el código, no te puedo poner un ejemplo mas detallado porque no sos muy especifico con la pregunta, si esto no te ayudo aclara mas cual es tu duda

```
 protected void dprTarea_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        string oficinas = lblagencia.Text;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn = new SqlConnection("server=172.16.1.124;    database=DBProAuxQP_QA;      user id=sa;                   password=SA123456789*;");
        conn.Open();

        string query = "select Fechacumplimiento from TTareasIngreso where descripcion='" + dprTarea.SelectedValue + "' ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        TxtFechaPago.Text = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder ahi detalle con una imagen espero que se pueda hacer he investigado no he encontrado la manera.soy nuevo en c# @Alejandro Ricotti

Comment: Hace lo que te dije, tenes que usar el evento SelectedIndexChanged. Para poder usarlo hace click en el DropDownList, abajo a la derecha donde te aparecen las propiedades hay un boton con una imagen de un rayo llamado eventos, ahí das doble click en SelectedIndexChanged y te va a crear el evento para que le puedas agregar codigo, ese evento lo que va a hacer es que cada vez que cambies el indice del DropDownList se ejecute el código, en el cual deberías hacer una consulta a la base de datos y traer los valores para modificar los TextBox @Pierro

Comment: Amigo puse este codigo no se si estara bien lo detallare en mi pregunta porfavor ayudameeeeeee te lo suplico  @alejandro Ricotti

Comment: cuando seleccione no me mostro nada :(

Comment: Debuguea y fíjate que te devuelve la consulta SQL. Supongo que esto es innecesario oficina = lblagencia.Text = Session["oficina"].ToString();. Ya que lo que queres buscar en la base de datos es lblagencia.Text y lo estas reemplazando con la variable de la Session @Pierro

Comment: Como el valor que vas a traer en la consulta es uno solo te conviene usar ExecuteScalar y en la Query cambiar a select Fechacumplimiento @Pierro

Comment: le puse cmd. ExecuteScalar() y me sale un error en  ExecuteScalar he modifcado como mi pregunta ahi esta lo que he modifcado

Comment: TxtFechaPago.Text = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();. Con eso solo alcanza, recorda modificar el Select de la query para que traiga un solo valor

Comment: Debuguea y fíjate que el valor de la variable oficinas sea correcto y ejecuta la query en la base de datos para que estés seguro de que este bien el resultado. Edite mi respuesta agregando codigo, fijate eso @Pierro

Comment: estoy bugueando desde en Load pero cuando selecciono el combobox no sale te puedo pasar mi codigo por correo ayudame plis

Comment: Proba el codigo que acabo de poner y si tenes algun problema comentalo por aca asi cualquier otra persona puede ayudarte tambien

Comment: ya lo puse mi codigo como me indicaste pero igual no me sale :(

Comment: @pierro Proba usando la consulta Sql en la base de datos a ver que resultado te trae

Comment: lo probre asi con la misma sintasis y si me arroja la fecha lo que deseo pero en el combobox no me atrae como si algo faltaria porque el SelectedIndexChanged no me atrae pero en mi sql si